# Where are the display configuration files in 14.04 LTS?

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display

My display configuration has become corrupted. It takes longer to start Ubuntu than usual, and I notice the monitor is flickering multiple times, like when it is changing video modes.

Since I first installed Ubuntu 14.04 using the default display driver, I noticed a bug that every few minutes corrupts a text character on the page. The character looks like a jumble of misaligned characters. As I drag the mouse near it, it corrects itself. It is a bit annoying.

Yesterday I tried the proprietary driver and it seemed to solve the problem. However, I switched drivers back and forth a couple of times, and all of a sudden I get a black screen when I log out. It turns out that the driver now blanks the secondary monitor. It thinks that my TV is the primary monitor, but I only use it to stream videos, and it is usually off.

I would like to inspect the files where the monitors are configured, but I cannot find anything close.

My system has an AMD A10-K7850K Kaveri processor with built-in GPUs.

Comment: Check in `/etc/X11/`

Comment: I have looked in /etc/X11/ and I didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 7):

To find the files where the monitors are currently configured, execute:

```
locate --existing monitors.xml
```